# Install JDK 1.7 and Eclipse using Chef on Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, chef-infra

I am new to chef and I need help installing Java on windows through chef. I found Java cookbook from chef supermarket but when I tried running the script, I kept getting bad URI error. It says "FATAL: No download url set for java installer". Has anyone faced this issue. And I also need to download eclipse but I haven't found anything online for that. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you must rehost certain Java installers yourself. If you are trying to install IBM Java, this is mandatory. If you are trying to install Oracle Java, you can also have Chef accept their download terms and conditions on your behalf. See [the examples](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java#examples) for more information on both.